# swap custom class object with swift default swap function

Tags: ios, swift, swap

I wanted to use default swap function in swift 5.0

This is what I have written

```
swap(&buyingCurrencyObj, &sellingCurrencyObj)
```

where

```
var sellingCurrencyObj = SellingCurrency()
var buyingCurrencyObj = BuyingCurrency()
```

but it says

```
Cannot convert value of type 'SellingCurrency' to expected argument type 'BuyingCurrency'
```

BuyingCurrency() and SellingCurrency() are my two class which has same fnctionality but with different parameters.

```
open class SellingCurrency {

public init() { }
    public var sellingCurrencyDisplayName:String?
    public var sellingCurrencyActive:Bool?
    public var sellingCurrencyCode:String?
    public var sellingCurrencyTradingPlatformID:String?
    public var sellingCurrencyID:String?
}
```

and

```
open class BuyingCurrency {
public init() { }
    public var buyingCurrencyDisplayName:String?
    public var buyingCurrencyActive:Bool?
    public var buyingCurrencyCode:String?
    public var buyingCurrencyTradingPlatformID:String?
    public var buyingCurrencyID:String?
}
```

I want to swap these two class objects.
How can use default Swap function on custom class object.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you expecting it to work? They are 2 different types and you can swap 2 different types using a swap operation. And if they have same kind of data, why make 2 different types? Why haven't you created a single type `Currency` and made 2 instances of it?

Comment: I am just using object of these. I want to swap objects for the same. so after swap Selling Object become Buying and Buying object to become selling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of the input arguments of `swap` need to match. I'd suggest creating a common protocol, to which both of your classes conform, then storing your variables as the protocol.

```
protocol Currency {
    var displayName: String? { get }
    var active: Bool? { get }
    var currencyCode: String? { get }
    var tradingPlatformID: String? { get }
    var currencyID: String? { get }
}

open class SellingCurrency: Currency {
    public init() { }
    public var displayName: String?
    public var active: Bool?
    public var currencyCode: String?
    public var tradingPlatformID: String?
    public var currencyID: String?
}

open class BuyingCurrency: Currency {
    public init() { }
    public var displayName: String?
    public var active: Bool?
    public var currencyCode: String?
    public var tradingPlatformID: String?
    public var currencyID: String?
}

var buyingCurrency: Currency = BuyingCurrency()
var sellingCurrency: Currency = SellingCurrency()

swap(&buyingCurrency, &sellingCurrency)
```

A couple of general improvements to your code:

- Prefixing variable names with the name of the type adds no value whatsoever, but makes readability much worse, so I'd strongly advise against doing that.
- Making all properties of a type `Optional` is usually a massive code smell - only make properties `Optional`, which really need to be `Optional`.

Comment: :- Noted your points and will work accordingly. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Since both the `SellingCurrency` and `BuyingCurrency` have same kind of data, you can simply create a single `class` that represent both of them instead of having 2 separate types,

```
open class Currency {
    public var displayName:String?
    public var active:Bool?
    public var code:String?
    public var tradingPlatformID:String?
    public var ID:String?
}
```

Now, make 2 instances of `Currency` type - one for buying and another for selling,

```
var sellingCurrencyObj = Currency()
var buyingCurrencyObj = Currency()
```

Next, use `swap(_:_:)` operation on the above instances,

```
swap(&sellingCurrencyObj, &buyingCurrencyObj)
```